# Vim pymode in windows

Tags: python, vim

I am trying to use pymode in Windows (https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode) but I am having a hard time.
I have managed to clone it into C:\Users[USER].vim\pack\python-mode\start\python-mode and vim seems to run normally in python 2 (this is what `:python import.sys; sys.version()` prints:

```
2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:22:17) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
```

But when I try using `:help pymode` it says nothing is founds. Moreover, one of the reasons I would like to use pymode is that I would like to switch vim to python 3.

Any help is appreciated, I am beginner with Vim (and I am using windows, which I have the impression is a not common choice for vim users).
Thanks.

Comment: What version of vim are you using?

Comment: Did you follow all the install instructions on the github link you provided? there seems to be some Windows specific instructions there too.

On a side note, I don't get why people want to make `vim` into a full-blown IDE, isn't a much better approach to have a `vim` editor plugin for the IDE?

Comment: Im using vim version 8.1.2231. To randomfigure, which IDE could I use vim with? Thanks.